# Does the school have access to email content of my personal email if logged into Chrome with my school account?

Tags: email, chrome

I sent an email to somebody with my personal email account (not my school email account). However, when using my personal email, I am doing it with a Chrome browser that I am logged in to using my school account. Can the school know who I am messaging and the content of that message? I did not turn on sync.

Comment: Did you do this while on the school's network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Not inherently. Logging into a managed Google account in Chrome does not, by default, give the administrator any ability to see or control what you do; it simply controls what account Chrome uses for things like loading your preferences and syncing anything that is set up to sync (which might include browsing history - in the form of URLs, not page content - but by default even that isn't enabled).

However, administrators do have quite considerable control over managed Chrome instances. Most notably, they can forcibly install extensions in your browser, without your approval or even notification. Normally this is done for completely reasonable and benign reasons, like ensuring you have an extension that is necessary to everybody in the organization (e.g. as a student, it might be something that is required by their remote test-taking software), or providing a tool they expect users to find valuable (e.g. my work installs a password manager and the "GoLinks" extension, both of which we are encouraged to use to make our jobs easier).

There's no guarantee that the extensions are so benign, though. Extensions can contain outright malware, doing things like capturing everything you see or do in the browser and sending it elsewhere, modifying pages and actions you take, spying on you using the camera or microphone (although AFAIK you do have to approve this first, you don't necessarily know where the request is coming from or what it's for, and if you have a page that already has those permissions then an extension could use that without asking for more), offering you malicious downloads (though not forcing you to save them or open them), and more. Extensions are still limited by the browser sandbox (they can't directly access your file system or most hardware) and there are limits to the permissions they can get even within the browser (e.g. AFAIK there's no way to prevent Chrome from revealing when a tab is listening to/watching you), but there's still quite a lot of room for harm, especially if you use the browser for many sensitive things (like email, social media or other reputation-sensitive stuff, banking/shopping/securities/cryptocurrency, etc.).

---

In this case, you're almost certainly fine. The school has no legitimate interest in your personal email, so there'd be a huge uproar if it was found to be spying on it. Furthermore, writing malware - malicious extensions included - is a skill and requires effort, and I doubt the school would have bothered either purchasing this or paying for somebody to write it. It might also open the school to legal liabilities; even if you technically signed something saying you wouldn't use school property for personal use / you authorize the school to monitor your activity, there are limits to what the courts will allow contracts to get up to (as an example, you can legally sign something giving away your child, but you *can't* legally be *tricked* into doing this; it needs to be extremely clear what you're agreeing to, and "I agree to the terms and conditions" checkboxes generally wouldn't cut it).

My recommendation here: treat this as a learning opportunity. Don't use somebody else's hardware, or hardware on which you're running somebody else's software, for anything that you'd care if the other party got access to. In fact, in general, don't use it for personal stuff. Relatedly, don't sign into school/corporate/government accounts on personal devices or, if you must, create an isolated profile for this (either a full OS user profile, or at least a different Chrome profile; different Chrome profiles have independent extension lists and don't allow one to affect another).